# pyflink TableException: Failed to execute sql

Tags: apache-flink, pyflink

I use pyflink to run flink streaming, if I run flink with StandAlone mode, it works, but run flink with yarn-per-job mode, it failed, report "pyflink.util.exceptions.TableException: Failed to execute sql"

yarn per job command is: flink run -t yarn-per-job -Djobmanager.memory.process.size=1024mb -Dtaskmanager.memory.process.size=2048mb -ynm flink-cluster -Dtaskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots=2 -pyfs cluster.py ...

standalone command is: flink run -pyfs cluster.py ...

The python environment archive attached in cluster.py.

```
env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
env_settings = EnvironmentSettings.new_instance().in_streaming_mode().use_blink_planner().build()
t_env = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env, environment_settings=env_settings)

curr_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
jars = f"""
file://{curr_path}/jars/flink-sql-connector-kafka_2.11-1.13.1.jar;
file://{curr_path}/jars/force-shading-1.13.1.jar"""
    
t_env.get_config().get_configuration().set_string("pipeline.jars", jars)
t_env.add_python_archive("%s/requirements/flink.zip" % curr_path)
t_env.get_config().set_python_executable("flink.zip/flink/bin/python")
env.set_stream_time_characteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)
env.set_parallelism(2)
env.get_config().set_auto_watermark_interval(10000)
t_env.get_config().get_configuration().set_boolean("python.fn-execution.memory.managed", True)
parse_log = udaf(LogParser(parsing_params),
                 input_types=[DataTypes.STRING(), DataTypes.STRING(), DataTypes.STRING(), DataTypes.STRING(),
                                  DataTypes.STRING(), DataTypes.TIMESTAMP(3)],
                     result_type=DataTypes.STRING(), func_type="pandas")
process_ad = udf(ADProcessor(ad_params), result_type=DataTypes.STRING())

t_env.create_temporary_function('log_parsing_process', parse_log)
t_env.create_temporary_function('ad_process', process_ad)

tumble_window = Tumble.over("5.minutes").on("time_ltz").alias("w")

t_env.execute_sql(f"""
            CREATE TABLE source_table(
                ip VARCHAR,               -- ip address
                raws VARCHAR,             -- message
                host VARCHAR,             -- host
                log_type VARCHAR,         -- type
                system_name VARCHAR,      -- system
                ts BIGINT,
                time_ltz AS TO_TIMESTAMP_LTZ(ts, 3),
                WATERMARK FOR time_ltz AS time_ltz - INTERVAL '5' SECOND
            ) WITH (
                'connector' = 'kafka',
                'topic' = '{source_topic}',
                'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '{source_servers}',
                'properties.group.id' = '{group_id}',
                'scan.startup.mode' = '{auto_offset_reset}',
                'format' = 'json'
            )
            """)

sink_sql = f"""
        CREATE TABLE sink (
            alert VARCHAR,           -- alert
            start_time timestamp(3), -- window start timestamp
            end_time timestamp(3)    -- window end timestamp
        ) with (
            'connector' = 'kafka',
            'topic' = '{sink_topic}',
            'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '{sink_servers}',
            'json.fail-on-missing-field' = 'false',
            'json.ignore-parse-errors' = 'true',
            'format' = 'json'
        )"""

t_env.execute_sql(sink_sql)

t_env.get_config().set_null_check(False)

source_table = t_env.from_path('source_table')
sink_table = source_table.window(tumble_window) \
        .group_by("w, log_type") \
        .select("log_parsing_process(ip, raws, host, log_type, system_name, time_ltz) AS pattern, "
                "w.start AS start_time, "
                "w.end AS end_time") \
        .select("ad_process(pattern, start_time, end_time) AS alert, start_time, end_time")

sink_table.execute_insert("sink")
```

Error is:

```
File "/tmp/pyflink/xxxx/xxxx/workerbee/log_exception_detection_run_on_diff_mode.py ,line 148, in run_flink sink_table_execute_insert("test_sink")
File "/opt/flink/flink-1.13.1_scala_2.12/opt/python/pyflink.zip/pyflink/table/table.py, line 1056 in execute_insert
File "/opt/flink/flink-1.13.1_scala_2.12/opt/python/py4j-0.10.8.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1286, in __call__
File "/opt/flink/flink-1.13.1_scala_2.12/opt/python/pyflink.zip/pyflink/util/exceptions.py", line 163, in deco
pyflink.util.exceptions.TableException: Failed to execute sql
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:777)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:742)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableImpl.executeInsert(TableImpl.java:572)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMetondAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMetondAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.hava:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.hava:498)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramAbortException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Python process exits with code: 1
```

nodemanager log:

```
INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: launchContainer: [bash, /opt/hadoop_data/tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/applicatino_I1644370510310_0002/container_I1644370510310_0002_03_000001/default_container_executor.sh]
WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Exit code from container container_I1644370510310_0002_03_000001 is : 1
WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Exception from container-launch with container ID: container_I1644370510310_0002_03_000001 and exit exit code: 1
ExitCodeException exitCode=1:
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java: 1008)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java: 901)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExceutor.execute(Shell.java:1213
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:309)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.launchContainer(ContainerLaunch.java:585)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.Call(ContainerLaunch.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.Call(ContainerLaunch.java:103)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPollExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPollExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPollExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPollExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor: Exception from container-launch.
INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor: container id: container_I1644370510310_0002_03_000001
INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor: Exit code: 1
WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch: Container launch failed : Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_I1644370510310_0002_03_000001 transitioned from RUNNING to EXITED_WITH_FAILURE
```

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].

Comment: The log text is in remote server on customer site, I can not copy or download it, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a classloader related issue. classloader.check-leaked-classloader configuration can refer to https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/zh/docs/deployment/config/

In addition, you can try to use add_jar api instead of setting pipeline.jars config directly

```
def add_jars(self, *jars_path: str):
        """
        Adds a list of jar files that will be uploaded to the cluster and referenced by the job.
    
        :param jars_path: Path of jars.
        """
        add_jars_to_context_class_loader(jars_path)
        jvm = get_gateway().jvm
        jars_key = jvm.org.apache.flink.configuration.PipelineOptions.JARS.key()
        env_config = jvm.org.apache.flink.python.util.PythonConfigUtil \
            .getEnvironmentConfig(self._j_stream_execution_environment)
        old_jar_paths = env_config.getString(jars_key, None)
        joined_jars_path = ';'.join(jars_path)
        if old_jar_paths and old_jar_paths.strip():
            joined_jars_path = ';'.join([old_jar_paths, joined_jars_path])
        env_config.setString(jars_key, joined_jars_path)
```

Comment: first thank your reply, which variable should I refer to in getEnvironmentConfig because my pyflink entrypoint is function not class to replace self._j_stream_execution_environment? if I used env defined in my code, it reported 'StreamExecutionEnvironment' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'

Comment: env.add_jars("file:///my/jar/path/connector1.jar", "file:///my/jar/path/connector2.jar")

Comment: Is it using the add_jars interface?

Comment: after that i user your method, and use the env.add_jars interface, it still the "Failed to execute sql" error

Comment: Maybe you can provide the updated code and error message

Comment: I updated parts of error

Answer (score 0):

after debug and check, finally I found the issue is I missed some flink hadoop jar packages:

```
commons-cli-1.4.jar
flink-shaded-hadoop-3-uber-3.1.1.7.2.1.0-327-9.0.jar
hadoop-yarn-api-3.3.1.jar
```